# @JsonIgnore not working after upgrading to spring 4.1.6

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have tried all the solutions provided on SO [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19894955/spring-jsonignore-not-working)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14664282/jacksons-jsonignore) and many others but nothing seems to solve my problem. I am getting below exception

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]-
```

I am not getting why spring using `fasterxml.jackson` while with previous version it was using it from `codehaus`

previous spring version 3.1.2.Release
current spring version 4.1.6.Release

Comment: besides the package name update, I guess this is related to transacitons (Hibernate, JPA etc.), would you provide the related stacktrace and code?

Comment: @hsluo thanks for your reply, I have solved this problem by changing codehaus jackson to fasterxml jackson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do quite the opposite to what is recommended in the links you've posted, so change the package of your Jackson classes from `org.codehaus.jackson` to `com.fasterxml.jackson`

As of *Spring Framework 4.1*, the minimum jackson version should be 2.1 [(2.3 recommended)](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Migrating-from-earlier-versions-of-the-Spring-Framework#libraries). The relevent change, and the suspected cause of your issue is that with jackson 2.x there has been a package shift as well

> - Java package used is "com.fasterxml.jackson" (instead of "org.codehaus.jackson")
> - Maven group ids begin with"com.fasterxml.jackson" (instead of "org.codehaus.jackson")

If you're using maven just replace your current jackson dependencies with this single one

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of Spring used Jackson 1.9, which has classes in the org.codehaus.jackson package. Spring 4.1.6.Release uses Jackson 2.x, which has its classes in com.fasterxml.jackson package. Therefore old annotations are simply ignored.